# Compare Two Named Pipe Handles

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes, handle

Is it possible to compare two HANDLE objects of the Named Pipe variety?

If, for example, I have a list of all active Handles via Process Explorer or some similar tool, could I compare a given Handle to all active Handles to determine which Handle from the list point towards the same Named Pipe?

I can't use the native function NtQueryObject here sadly, too unstable.

I've also tried to simply determine the name of the named pipe given it's handle using GetFinalPathNameByHandle but it appears to be incompatible with named pipe handles.

Comment: Even if you had all handle values, that wouldn't mean you have access rights.

Comment: But say hypothetically I do have access rights.  Is there a way to compare them?

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows 10 there is a reliable way using [`CompareObjectHandles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt438733.aspx)